# ReferenceError: Set is not defined. Error utilizing Set data structure in Ionic app

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app that uses the set data structure in one of it's method. When I try to run the app on my android device(Android 5.0.2,API 21), I run into this error

```
ReferenceError: Set is not defined
at Object.myMethod
```

Here is a code snippet showing the line responsible for the error

```
myMethod: function(userid) {


      var user = [];

      var service = this;
      var userIDs = new Set();
      var promises = [];
    ...}
```

I am not a javascript guru but it seems to me that it might be a problem with the android web view on my device not having a built in implementation of the Set data structure. To further confuse matters, I tested this same app on another device(HTC One M8(Android 5.0.1,API 21)) and it worked fine with no errors shown. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You should try a polyfill for those devices that does not support `Set`:

https://github.com/medikoo/es6-set

Comment: thanks. Not sure how to do this for an ionic app. I installed the es6-set on my computer as instructed but I'm not sure where to put the 'var Set = require('es6-set');' line.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the most optimal option, but you could use dictionary with boolean values...

```
var userIDs = {};
userID["anyUserId"] = true;
```